# Great news regarding JSE

Tags: discussion, joomla

Great news!

George Wilson was talking to Jessica Dunbar at the Joomla World Conference and it turns out Joomla will be endorsing Joomla Stack Exchange. This will mean references to the site on the official Joomla Documentation with some possible (can't confirm this) advertisement on the official Joomla site.

Nothing to discuss, just thought I'd let you guys know :)

Comment: Sweet! That's great news!

Comment: Somebody should get flowers for this.

Comment: Well I'm still waiting for my previous batch of flowers

Comment: WOOT! that's awesome

Answer (score 2):

As far as I am concerned (and I'll admit to being a StackExchange fan-boy), JSX is a superior site structure versus classic forums and mailing lists for many reasons.  I find the comparison to be a "no-contest".

I have been and will continue to urge and support Joomla users that I meet via my local Meetup group and future conferences to become more active on JSX regardless of what they "have to offer".  When more people get involved and they are shown the benefits of being a citizen of the site, everyone wins.

Joomla has too many communication channels for support and this spreads the talented problem solvers too thin.  If there is a better platform than the Q&A here, I have yet to find it.  Let's all endeavor to do more to make this site a better resource.  Having this echoed from the Joomla leadership can only help.

Comment: Couldn't agree more. The SE network has one major advantage over the forum, in that everything is kept as on-topic and not "I'm having the same issue too". SEO is brill and answers can be found rapidly without having to sift through loads of posts. I've not yet been to a local Joomla meetup, only JAB and code sprints for J4 but would be open to trying the meetup.

Answer (score 1):

Send something to Jess but I'll take credit for turning her on to JSE :) .  We're friends and she picked up on one of my posts and asked if they should be tweeting it.  I said HELL YES.

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering if anything came of this and [JSE was added to the help menu in the Joomla back-end in April 2015](https://issues.joomla.org/tracker/joomla-cms/6868).

Comment: Yup, I believe that was the final result of the talk.